# Copy and paste from column to row in excel using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

Is there any way to copy and paste from Column to Row in excel using power shell tried above is my script. I want around more 30 Column to pasted in Row in another sheet. I have tired various combination.. I am able to copy but while pasting in row e.g. O2 row it fails.

I wanted column A1:A to be copied to row O2,P2 ,r2 .... It like transpose from column to row. I am not getting any error. Basically, it as not copying from column to row. Tried giving row =2 and column 2 Row++ but it didn't work.

Below method is one of the way a tired.

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt ("Enter the Sheet Location")
$xl   = New-Object -ComObject excel.application

$xl.visible = $true

$wbk = $xl.Workbooks.open($path)
$ws1 = $wbk.WorkSheets.item("Old Data")
$ws2 = $wbk.WorkSheets.item("New Data")

$ws1.activate()

#Pasting  Specific Name  from first column

$xlPasteValues = -4163          # Values only, not formulas
$xlCellTypeLastCell = 11        # to find last used cell

$used = $ws1.usedRange
$lastCell = $used.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell)
$column = $lastCell.column
$range = $ws1.UsedRange

[void]$ws1.Range("A2$column").Copy()
[void]$ws2.Range("O18:O18").PasteSpecial(-4163) 

$ws2.activate()

#Pasting Monthly perfomance

$xlPasteValues = -4163          # Values only, not formulas
$xlCellTypeLastCell = 11        # to find last used cell

$used = $ws1.usedRange
$lastCell = $used.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell)
$column = $lastCell.column
$range = $ws1.UsedRange

[void]$ws1.Range("B2$column").Copy()
[void]$ws2.Range("O8:O8").PasteSpecial(-4163) 

$ws2.activate()
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49846194/edit) your question and post the the comments in there. Where is `$row` assigned? What error do you get when it fails?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49846194/edit) your question and post the the comments in there

Answer (score 0):

[The `PasteSpecial` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial.aspx) accepts multiple arguments.

```
Object PasteSpecial(
    XlPasteType Paste,
    XlPasteSpecialOperation Operation,
    Object SkipBlanks,
    Object Transpose
)
```

The fourth argument is `Transpose`, which is `false`  by default. That's the one you want.

The second argument is the `Operation`, which accepts `XlPasteSpecialOperation` enumerations - [specified here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241404(v=office.12).aspx). The third argument is `SkipBlank`, which can be `true` or `false`. Both of these arguments as well as transpose are optional, which is why `PasteSpecial` in your original code works.

```
# Option 1 - specify all arguments.

$xlPasteValues = -4163
$xlPasteSpecialOperationNone = -4142    # default

[void]$ws2.Range("O2").PasteSpecial($xlPasteValues,$xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,$false,$true)
```

---

```
# Option 2 - skip what's not required

$xlPasteValues = -4163

[void]$ws2.Range("O2").PasteSpecial($xlPasteValues, [System.Type]::Missing, [System.Type]::Missing, $true)
```

Comment: I tired both option they are working fine now, But the challenge it is not taking entire column till the last data eg, if i have 98 in column only 6 are getting copied. rest are not selected. Kindly advice for the same.

Answer (score 0):

this option already, i have tired but it is not what i can to achieve because it paste unique value  as column has different data in it all need to be pasted in row.
$xlPasteValues = -4163

[void]$ws2.Range("O2").PasteSpecial($xlPasteValues, [System.Type]::Missing, [System.Type]::Missing, $true)